# Will lowering my salary expectations help me find a job faster?

Tags: software-industry, salary

I have been on 5 interviews last month. I have gotten 4 rejections and the fifth is uncertain. I know at least one of the rejections was not salary based. Furthermore I have checked my salary expectation against several websites for location, experience, and skills and I am about average. I work in Business Intelligence.

Will lowering the number help me find a job faster?

Counterexample: I was just in contact with a recruiter, I told him my lower salary. He told me the company had alotted $x, which was $10k more than I usually ask.

Comment: What job position are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I work in recruitment. It is possible their is a disconnect between the experience, or perceived experience found on your resume, and what comes across in the interviews.  Is your CV descriptive enough and well matched to the roles you are being interviewed for?

Another alternative is that you are simply unlucky, and really strong candidates are beating you to the punch.  What level are we talking about here - analyst, senior salesperson, etc.?

To answer directly - it doesn't sound like money is the issue based on what you have described.  It would be good to understand the situation in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not really helpful. Lower salary demands will indicate that you are not worth more, and will likely indicate that you are not capable of handling the job.

Say the company is looking for someone worth $50,000 and offering $50,000. If you apply for $40,000 you will appear not to be able to fill that position.

Even if you improved your chances of getting the job, it means you make a lot less money!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that undervaluing yourself is likely to work the opposite way. People will think you aren't good enough to command the salary they had in mind.

Bear in mind 4-5 rejections is not many. Depending on the economy and the hiring at the time I have looked I have gotten offers from the first interview or not even gotten an interview until I sent out over 100 resumes (I graduated in a very bad year for entry level hiring).  And hiring is a competition, if you continually get rejected for the same level jobs, you may be applying for jobs at the wrong level. If you want to be a senior whatchamacallit with 3 years experience, you had better have a lot of accomplishments to show to compete with the people who have been senior whatchamacallits for ten years.

Now what you can do is try to figure out if you can improve your interviewing skills. can you see a pattern to the questions that you didn't feel you did well on? Are they the hard skills questions or the soft ones? Did you just not know the answer or did you get to nervous to remember it? Are you failing to sell your strong points?

Like anything else interviewing gets better with practice. So practice by writing out all the questions you can think of that people have asked (and any others that you woudl ask someone if you were interviewing them for the position you want) and then video yourself answering them and do it over and over again until you improve how you present yourself and until you can answer the questions relatively easily. It's painful to practice by videotaping but it is hands down the best way to improve if you are serious about getting better at interviewing or public presentations of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering your Salary ask will open more positions to you. As you have more options to choose from as you can apply to lower level jobs as well as more Sr ones. But once you get the interview and they know your salary ask, I don't think it matters.

So by all mean apply to lower level Jobs **as well as** the more Sr ones. **-But when asked about salary only mention the lower rate for the lower level jobs.**